# SFP+ 10GbE Module Interface

Tags: ethernet, transceiver

I'm in the process of learning about how SFP+ modules work under the hood. I chose a 10GBASE-T transceiver module as my case study. The module I chose is said to be complaint with SFF-8431 spec, so when I look this up on Wikipedia:

[image]

<strike>It looks like the interface would be XGMII.</strike> This interface is
the "MDI" interface, correct?  Does the transceiver implements the entire PHY (LDPC PCS, PMA, AN) or is it just a glorified ADC/DAC?

How would I figure out what the interface should be for ones that don't list anything under "MAC block to a PHY chip?"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The interface in this case, I belive, is called SFI.  Definitely not XGMII (32-bit DDR, was never really seen off-chip) or XAUI (4 lanes of 3.25 Gbps).  It's exactly the same as the interface to a 10GBASE-R optical module.

Basically, you can think of the SFP+ to BASE-T module as a media converter - it receives 10GBASE-R on one end, and produces 10GBASE-T on the other end, and vise versa.  So in the transmit direction, it will receive 64b/66b encoded and scrambled 10GBASE-R data, then convert that to 10GBASE-T including the multilevel encoding, FEC, etc.  In the receive direction, it will receive the 10GBASE-T data, detect the symbols, decode the FEC, and transmit it again as 64b/66b encoded 10GBASE-R data.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these diagrams will help. It looks like XGMII is implemented between the mac and packet processor.
[image]

[image]
Source: https://4donline.ihs.com/images/VipMasterIC/IC/TXII/TXIIS100070/TXIIS182093-1.pdf?hkey=EC6BD57738AE6E33B588C5F9AD3CEFA7

Another good datasheet is this one: https://www.renesas.com/us/en/www/doc/datasheet/bbt3420.pdf

Comment: The SFP(+) module is typically only the right half of the box labelled "PHY/Optics" in your diagram. It is sometimes called the PMA (physical medium attach) or PMD (physical medium dependent) sublayer.

Comment: Looking at the schematic of a PCB that includes a SFP+ cage, there's only two pairs (a single Tx pair and a single Rx pair), so I'm still a little bit confused why it lists XGMII, which has 8 pairs. If it truly only implements the PMA, which spec would describe the hardware interface between the PCS and PHY?

Comment: @sittinhawk The TX/RX pairs are for an XAUI interface, which is a 10Gbps on PCB interface. Otherwise you'd need a phy. Some phy's only use XAUI

Comment: So is XAUI flexible on how many lanes it needs? You show 4 TX/RX pairs in the picture, but the SFP+ pinout definitely only has pins for 1 TX/RX pair. The single pair works the same, you just need to go 4 times faster than if you had the 4 pairs?

Comment: @SittinHawk, this is not a XAUI interface. In the Ethernet spec (IEEE 802.3-2018 Clause 52) it's called a "Medium Dependent Interface (MDI)". Users are free to use an SFP+ module or any other kind they like, which can have whatever design they like. The SFP+ design is specified in chapter 3 of SFF-8431. But Ethernet does not require you to use this interface.

Comment: At higher rates (100, 400 Gbps) Ethernet gets more specific about the host-module interface, but 10 Gbps was a free-for-all.

Comment: "10 Gbps was a free-for-all" so figuring out the details of this interface will require getting documentation from the manufacturer of the module? Is there at least a "typical" interface or do you know the most common interface used?

Comment: @SittinHawk, if you're using SFP+, then refer to SFF-8431. If you want to use a different module type (XPak, Xenpak, X2, ...) then you'll need to find the documentation for that type.

Comment: Practically, the electrical requirements are very similar for all of them.

Comment: I do have the SFF-8431 specification, and it clearly defines voltages, data eye timing parameters, and test methodology, but that's it. I am still wondering about the higher level stuff. At the very least, the module needs to convert a digital word into the double-square PAM-16 modulated waveform. So double-square PAM-16 has 128 discrete constellation mappings, so would I just send a 7-bit word? A stream of 7-bit words? LSb first, MSb first? 8b/10b? Is there any kind of framing control characters? I feel like there are a lot of details that I can't seem to find.

Comment: @SittinHawk, FYI, you need to "@" someone if you want them to know you're talking to them.

Comment: I mainly work with optics, not copper transceivers, so I don't know about the PAM-16 modulation. But generally the transceiver expects to receive 8b/10b encoded data. That code has enough information for the module to figure out the word boundaries, if it needs to (but optical transceivers generally don't --- they just send out the same symbols they receive).

Comment: @ThePhoton Okay thanks for the guidance. I could believe 8b/10b encoded data is used, but it would still be nice to have something written in a spec or user guide that indicates this (I'm guessing there is something written, but I am just having trouble finding it).

Comment: @SittinHawk I might have been wrong about the coding. Transceivers that have 4 lane interfaces may use 8b/10b, but transceivers with 1-lane interfaces (like SFP+) might use 64b/66b encoding. See IEEE 802.3-2018 clause 52.  (10 Gb/s * (66/64) = 10.3125 Gbaud, which is the 10 GbE serial line rate, so I'm pretty sure 64b/66b is correct for 10 GbE serial) I worked on a 10GbE X2 transceiver design (4-lane interface) years ago but then I was out of the Ethernet business during the time when SFP+ was developed, so I don't have first-hand knowledge of all the details of SFP+.

Comment: And now I see that 10GBase-T uses 64b/65b encoding, which I've never worked with before.